# Dynamodb key made up of 3 fields

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say I have an RDBMS table with a composite primary key e,g field1,field2,field3 which uniquely identify a record in the table. How can I model this on Dynamodb as it appears the primary on Dynamodb can only be made up of two fields (e.g a partition key and sort key)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to somehow combine them into one value (such as concatenation with a field delimiter). For e.g. field1_field2_field3 as the partition key. If you happen to need sorting, you may also use sort key. You would also be able to search on bases for these fields for e.g. field1_ or *field2* or _field3

Refrence: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/